# How to run a Fortran (.EXE) file from Win7 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: fortran, fortran77

My question is regarding the compilation of a FORTRAN program. I have a Windows 7 32-bit .exe file, generated by compiling a FORTRAN code (F771 compiler), which does not work on 64 bit machine. How do I run this generated .exe file on 64-bit machine?

Is there any necessity to define different syntax during compilation of program for individual bit machine?

Comment: what is m/c? In general, code compiled for x86 will run on x86_64...

Comment: I edited your question to replace m/c with machine - I assume that this is what m/c meant. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: AFAIK you will have to recompile your program for every new system that you want to run your code on. So to run on your 64-bit machine you will have to compile you code on that machine, you can't just copy your 32-bit .exe from one system to another and expect it to work.

Comment: Can you be specific as to the way in which it does not work ?  You must, I think, get some sort of informative error message.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments...... I have a simply fortran compiler i install it on X64 and X86 too. But both gives same results(i.e., after compilation .exe get generated and run too but it not working in proper way(means program get exit after some steps)). However, I have compiled the program on X64(64 bit) linux based machine(Red Hat) the program works fine. Have you any suggestions to this concern or any procedure to run linux based executable run on Windows X64 bit platform. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Vijay This is a different question to what you have posed in your question. Please edit your question giving as much detail about your problem as possible, including as much source code as reasonable, the error messages you get and what is your expected outcome (i.e. how does the output varying when running on Linux vs. Windows machines)

Comment: Dear Chris, in earlier post i've mentioned the error i.e program get exit after some steps in Windows but in linux it works fine. Sorry because of some confidential issue, I couldn't post sourcecode. Please suggest answer to last line of previous post.

Comment: @Vijay so link to that question, explain why the answers you have gotten so far don't fix your problem and why you have started a new thread. Alternatively, if the answers to the other thread aren't what you want/were expecting then try editing that question. Unless you improve this question it is likely to be closed.

Comment: My question is that is there any procedure to used linux based executable on windows platform? Thanks in advance. Kindly forget about the main thread for a moment.

Comment: No, you have to recompile the program on your Windows system.

Comment: Dear Chris...! I have already compile the program on the windows machine(X64 and X86) the .exe file is also get generated. However the program won't run properly. Kindly note that, I used (gfortran) on both linux and windows to compile the program.

Comment: If you want to run a Linux-executable on a Window machine, you could install a virtual machine and install a Linux OS inside of that virtual machine.

Answer (score 3):

[SimplyFortran](http://simplyfortran.com/) is not a compiler, but an IDE designed to work with [GNU Fortran compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/). You say your program, after compilation, runs and exits with an error. Is the error really (literally) *program get exit after some steps*?

I've never used SimplyFortran for a prolonged time, but I doubt someone would make an error description of that kind, it being rather useless in giving a diagnose.

You say your program works fine on RedHat, meaning it is relatively okey, syntax wise. If it is a simple program, could you try compiling it from a command line, and then showing (if such exist) syntax errors that occur, or runtime errors that occur while running?

It is hard to say more based on the given data.